# Newton's gravity vs Einstein's gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, newtonian-gravity, speed-of-light, relativity

Hello so if i were to simplify the difference between gravity as seen from Newton and gravity as seen from Einstein, could i say that Einstein's gravity is just adding the fact that gravity does not exceed the speed of light and does not have an instantaneous effect on mass. Also that not not all matter has a gravitational pull with other matter at any distance.

sorry if i look stupid but I'm 14 and I'm really trying my best to figure out the difference between the two different theories as I'm very curious and LOVE astrophysics.

Comment: No, that's not how it works. Retarded gravitational potentials, i.e. a scalar gravitational field that is propagating at the speed of light makes the wrong predictions, even in the solar system, and it wouldn't describe compact objects like black holes, at all, neither could we do cosmology with it. See http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73061/ for a more detailed answer.

Comment: The difference between Einstein's gravity and Newton's, is simply that Einstein's formulation of gravity keeps the laws of physics invariant. That's about as simple as it gets really, the entire premise of relativity was built upon the notion that all laws of physics must be the same regardless of reference frames. Newton however, did not account for that at all so yeah...

Comment: @Horus: Relativity doesn't keep the laws of physics invariant under acceleration and it only does so to first order for objects in free fall under the influence of gravity. None of this would be enough, anyway, to construct general relativity, that takes some non-trivial assumptions in addition (and it's not unique, even for those assumptions). Newtonian mechanics is a fully "relativistic" theory, if you want, and it uses the equivalence principle already. These things were known even to Galileo and they are simply not enough to go from Newton to Einstein.

Comment: @CuriousOne Hi I actually did not understand any part of what you said is it possible if you could dumb it down a bit for a fourteen year old?

Comment: It means that Newtonian gravitational potential + speed of light = false in the solar system, false in the local universe and false in the entire observable universe. The technical proof of these things is a little harder, though.

Comment: @Horus I think i understood most of what you said. Thanks for the effort for educating me!

Comment: @CuriousOne I am aware of that fact, but OP here is 14 and clueless. I am just trying to distill it to a simple enough explanation first. Also by invariant I really meant covariant...I forgot the word sorry.

Comment: @CuriousOne hey thanks that really helped. Thanks so much.

Comment: @Horus: You aren't helping a clueless 14 year old OP by telling him falsehoods, though. Do you expect the OP to understand the meaning of "covariant"? I would have to look up the details... and I took general relativity twice... :-)

Comment: thanks all for the effort!At least I have a better understanding now thanks

Comment: @Raj Thapliyal: Newton's Universal Theory of Gravitation is an approximation to a special case of Einstein's General Theory of Relativity; if things are moving slowly (planetary speeds, slow compared to light), and are not too heavy (no ultradense objects), then Newtonian predictions and GR predict similar results - but Einstein is correct for the bending of light passing close to the sun, and also gets the orbit of Mercury correct.  Newtonian mechanics is still used for most practical things in this world because it is much, much simpler.

Comment: @CuriousOne Nope I did not expect him to understand the meaning of 'covariant' though there really is no better word (singular) for it. Yes it is my mistake for 'telling him falsehoods' as you so aptly put it, though it is more of a distillation rather than falsehood (opinions may vary) and perhaps given more time, I may have come up with a better explanation.

Comment: Newtonian gravity says that a ball accelerates towards the earth at 9.8m/s^2.  If you've studied a bit of algebra, you'd know that this is a parabola.  This would be accurate if the earth were a flat plane, but it is spherical.  A falling ball, if the earth were out of the way would not follow the path of a parabola but that of an ellipse, because it is really just an orbit that hits the earth prematurely.  Einstein's gravity takes that into consideration.  Impractical unless you're calculating satellite orbits.

Comment: @Neil The orbits in Newtonian gravity are ellipses too. Einstein's gravity simply added a precession to their orbits.

Comment: Far from looking stupid, you are to be commended for asking such an astute question at the age of 14.  Although your intuition was off base for gravity, the situation for the evolution of many advances in science does flow in an analogous way of thinking.  A good example is the progression: Newtonian Physics -> Quantum Physics (Schrodinger Equation) -> Relativistic Quantum Physics (Dirac Equation).

Answer (score 2):

It's tempting to imagine starting with Newton's theory of gravity and trying to extend it to end up with general relativity. The trouble is that Newtonian gravity and GR are formulated in utterly different ways. General relativity is a [metric theory](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=metric%20theory%20of%20gravity) with a completely different starting point to Newtonian gravity. While it's fairly easy to show that Newtonian gravity is the low speed, low energy density limit of GR there is no simple way to do the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

> Could I say that Einstein's gravity is just adding the fact that gravity does not exceed the speed of light and does not have an instantaneous effect on mass?

No, you cannot. You are not alone in making this mistake. Laplace made this very same mistake in the late 18th century and calculated that if light does have a finite speed, it must be at least 7 million times that of the speed of light. Poincaré made this same mistake about a century later and calculated that the speed of gravity must be at least 10<sup>17</sup> times that of the speed of light. [Even as late as 1998](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0375960198006501)<sup>1</sup>, a professional scientist with a PhD in astronomy made that very same mistake.

Suppose it's raining straight down and you run in an attempt to get out of the rain. Instead of just your head and shoulders getting wet, your running makes you get wet (in front) from head to toe. The vertical rain isn't so vertical anymore from your perspective. It appears to be coming from in front of you. This same issue appears when we observe the Sun; it appears to be 20 arc seconds ahead of where it "actually" is thanks to the finite speed of light. This same issue would arise if one merely added a time lag to Newtonian gravity. The solar system would fly apart in short order if that was all there was to general relativity.

General relativity does not make this mistake. There's a lot more to general relativity than a finite transmission speed. But to understand the details, you will need mathematics far beyond even that of a very smart 14 year old.

---

<sup>1</sup> **Note to future editors: DO NOT make the cited link into a reference.** That author's name is verboten in any answer authored by me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way of thinking about the difference between Newton's theory of gravity and Einstein's is to think about how they think of gravity itself.

Newton says that there is a force which all massive objects feel and gives a rule for what that force is.  There's no explanation for *how* the force comes about: it just exists.  There's no delay in the force: this is fine in Newton's world (which, but it's not fine in Einstein's.

Einstein says something entirely different: *there is no force of gravity*.  Instead, massive objects simply move on straight lines.  But as well as doing this, massive objects deform spacetime, which means that 'straight lines' are more complicated than they would be in a non-deformed spacetime.

Einstein's notion of gravity is hugely more compelling than Newton's:

- it gives an explanation of what gravity *is*, in terms of curvature;
- it is compatible with special relativity, as the deformation of spacetime by mass spreads through spacetime at a finite speed (which, of course, is the speed of light);
- but, in suitable limits, it reduces to Newton's theory and so is compatible with it, which is good since Newton's theory works very well in many cases.

Unfortunately, because gravity is treated as a modification of the arena in which things happen, the theory tends to be fairly hard to work with.

(Note: this is not meant as a full description of GR: I'm trying to aim at someone of 14!)