Revolution of Earth around Sun and angular momentum
Pardon me I am just a high school student.
On basis of the fact that gravitational force is delayed.
Since angular momentum of planets around is conserved due to force and position vector being parallel (i.e zero net torque).
Using fact that gravitational forces are delayed.Therefore the force acting on the planet will be based on position at certain time before and then the direction of the force and
present position might not came out to be parallel and therefore net torque should not be zero.
What's wrong in this reasoning?

There is no “delay” in $F=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r_{12}^2}$. Newtonian gravity is not relativistic. Are you being taught General Relativity in high school?

"angular momentum of planets around is conserved due to force and position vector being parallel" -- in what coordinate system does that hold?

Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/535344/

You can think of the gravitational force as being due to the gravitational field (or gravitational potential, or, if you want to think in terms of General Relativity, due to the curvature of spacetime), which the planet "feels" locally (in the immediate vicinity). So, even though the speed of interaction is limited by the speed of light, the information about the planet's position doesn't actually need to travel all the way to the Sun and back; it's more like rolling down a hill. But any change in the gravitational field (change in the "shape of the hill") would take time to propagate.

Newtonian gravity and General Relativity are two different theories that make slightly different predictions. Since you haven’t said which one you’re asking about, your question is unclear. The fact that your tags include both “newtonian-gravity” and “speed-of-light” indicates some confusion, since Newtonian gravity does not involve the speed of light.

He is "just" a high school student. The answer in the linked question says that the direction of force and position the Sun was are 8 minutes ago are not parallel because of very small relativistic corrections to simple speed of light delays. A classical answer involving just speed of light delays would show they are parallel.

@mmesser314 You can add an answer in the other post, as I think it makes more sense than to have a separate question for each knowledge level.. also OP didn't really explicitly state they want a "classical" explanation, they simply asked what is wrong with their reasoning, and they may be willing to learn beyond their current high school level.

He is "just" a high school student. In high school I certainly wasn’t taught that gravitational force is delayed. I was taught that it is instantaneous, as Newton theorized. Have things changed?

I put "just" in quotes because it is an astute question for a high school student. He no doubt has been taught $F = Gm_1m_2/r^2$, and that it takes light $8$ minutes to arrive from the Sun. He is putting the two together and asking about how speed of light delay affect the orbit. So I think a classical answer would be best for him. I was writing such an answer, but I lost it when the question was closed.

@mmesser314 To me, “classical” means “non-quantum”. In what sense are you using the word?

Non-relativistic.

@mmesser314 To me “non-relativistic” means $c=\infty$.

The high-school-appropriate resolution of Newton’s Law of Gravitation and the fact that light has a finite speed is that Newtonian gravity has absolutely nothing to do with light or its speed.

@mmesser314 Maybe you mean “post-Newtonian”, where you correct for finite $c$ without going full-GR. That would make a nice answer if the question gets reopened.

@Ghoster "Have things changed?" - I mean, life exists outside of high school, and information is available more than ever; it's normal for a student to try and assess, filter and reconcile different sources of knowledge into one coherent picture. Also, students often think there is one true way of looking at things, one way which is the answer, and don't necessarily fully understand what a theoretical model is, much less where one ends and the other begins.

@FilipMilovanović don't necessarily fully understand what a theoretical model is, much less where one ends and the other begins In my opinion it’s much more productive to teach that early than to teach relativistic gravity — and how it manages to conserve angular momentum — early.
